# Quasi compact topological space.

Tags: general-topology

A topological space $(X,T)$ is said to be quasi compact if every open covering has a finite refinement. Let f be a fuction from $(X,T)$ to another topological space $(Y,T')$ then f is said to be quasi compact if inverse image of every quasi compact open subset of Y is a quasi compact subset of X.

Recently I saw another definition of quasi compactness in the research paper On Door Spaces by Julian Dontchev which says that a function f from a topological space $(X,T)$ to another topological space $(Y,T')$ is called quasi compact if it satisfies the following condition:

Let $U$ be an open subset of $X$ such that inverse image of $f(U)$ is $U$ itself then $f(U)$ is open in $Y$.
My doubt is whether this two definitions are equivalent. If yes kindly post the proof.

Answer (score 2):

These certainly are not equivalent.  For instance, let both spaces be $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology.  The only quasicompact open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is the empty set, so trivially any map $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is quasicompact by the first definition.  But it's certainly not true that every map $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is quasicompact by the second definition.  For instance, $f(x)=x^2$ fails the definition for $U=\mathbb{R}$.